# How to add column to nested column

Tags: clickhouse, metabase

I have a table with nested column

```
...
a UInt64
b Nested (b1 String, b2 String)
c LowCardinality(String),
...
```

I want to update the table to be

```
...
a UInt64
b Nested (b1 String, b2 String, **b3 String**)
c LowCardinality(String),
...
```

I tried:

ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS b3 String AFTER b2

but I need the new column to be a part of Nested b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found an answer

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS b3 Array(LowCardinality(String)) AFTER b2
```

(In my case it urls.success. *urls is the nested)